# Rewrite Apache Condition not preventing rewrite from getting applied

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'm trying to only allow incoming requests to `/multi` if the `Content-Type` request header starts with `multipart/form-data`, while requests to other `POST`, `PUT`, or `DELETE` endpoints must always have the `application/json` `Content-Type`.

When doing the following in my web roots `.htaccess` file (no root access):

```
# Enforce multipart/form-data content type for /multi routes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/multi [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^multipart/form-data; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L,END]

# Enforce JSON content type for all other POST, PUT, and DELETE endpoints
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(POST|PUT|DELETE)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^application/json [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/multi [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L,END]
```

... and then sending a `POST /multi` with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, I get Apache's `400 Bad Request` Response. When I remove the second rewrite block, the request gets through. Why is the second rewrite block applied when sending a `POST /multi` with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, although I have the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/multi [NC]` condition in it, which should prevent it from being applied?

When I check the apache error logs while sending the request with the second rewrite block enabled, I have no error log at all. When I check the Apache Dom Log, I simply have that an incoming request to `/multi` yielded the `400` response. So it indeed seems to be to the fact that the second rewrite rule is applied, which makes no sense to me.

**Full .htaccess File**

```
# Prevent files whose name starts with ".ht" from frontend access
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

# Set global Rules for document root directory
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Require all granted

# Specify rewrite rules
RewriteEngine On

# Authorization Header seems to be stripped by default, hence explicitly enable it
# Doing it via the rewrite rule is not the native way of doing it, and would need an improved rule to avoid that an
# Authorization HTTP header with an empty value is still passed to PHP
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
# RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
CGIPassAuth On

# Enforce multipart/form-data content type for /multi route
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/multi [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^multipart/form-data; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L,END]

# Enforce JSON content type for all other POST, PUT, and DELETE endpoints (return a 400 Bad Request otherwise)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(POST|PUT|DELETE)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^application/json [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/multi [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L,END]

# Route all incoming requests through index.php, except if it's for existing files
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Ensure that png images, javascript and css files are all delivered with correct mime type. mod_mime must be enabled.
AddType application/javascript .js
AddType image/png .png
AddType text/css .css

# Add an 'Expires' HTTP header for all accessed js, css and png image files. mod_expires must be enabled.
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"

# Also add a Cache-Control HTTP header for the same cache lifetime of 1 year, to cover all browsers. mod_headers needed.
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|png)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=31536000"
</FilesMatch>

# Define Image Uploads directory, to be able to access img uploads while uploads are kept outside from document root
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /uploads/imgs/$1 [L]

# Ensure that all icons are delivered with the image/jpeg MIME type
RewriteRule ^icons/ - [E=CONTENT_TYPE:image/png]
```

Comment: By “web roots” do you mean the document root directory? What other directives do you have in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Yep I mean the document root. I'll update the question with remaining contents of the `.htaccess` file. The comments always explain why I did what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
> ```

You have a front-controller pattern later in the `.htaccess` file that rewrites the request to `/index.php`. And since this rule only has the `L` flag (as opposed to `END`) the rewriting engine starts over with the rewritten URL. (In a `.htaccess` context the rewrite engine loops until it passes through unchanged).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/multi [NC]
> ```

During the second pass by the rewrite engine the URL is now `/index.php` (ie. *not* `/multi`) so the above condition is successful and the second rule is triggered, sending a 400 response. (The `REQUEST_URI` server variable is updated between passes by the rewrite engine.)

This "looping" by the rewrite engine is an additional complexity (and "feature") when using mod_rewrite in a *directory*/`.htaccess` context. It does not happen (by default) when used in a *server* (or *vitualhost*) context (unless you explicitly trigger this behaviour with the `PT` flag).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^multipart/form-data; [NC]
> ```

*Aside:* It looks like that request would be blocked by the first rule, since you appear to have an erroneous(?) `;` at the end of the regex? (ie. a request with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` only would satisfy the above *negated* condition.)

You need to either:

- Use the `END` flag instead on the later rewrite to `/index.php` (the front-controller), which stops all processing by the rewrite engine. For example:

  ```
  :
  RewriteRule . index.php [END]
  ```

  (You don't need the slash prefix on the substitution string in the case of an internal rewrite. But you have a `RewriteBase` directive anyway, which is also not necessary here.)

*OR*

- Instead of using `REQUEST_URI` in the second rule (which gets updated by the rewrite engine) to test the requested URL, use `THE_REQUEST` instead, which contains the first line of the request headers and does not get updated. `THE_REQUEST` would contain a string of the form `POST /multi/foo HTTP/1.1`. For example, instead of the `REQUEST_URI` condition, you would use something like the following instead:

  ```
  # Check the URL as requested by the client, not the rewritten URL
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/multi
  ```

*OR*

- Make sure the second rule only applies to the initial request from the client and not the written request (by the later rule). For this you can add an additional *condition* (first) and check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable. This is *empty* on the initial request and set to `200` (as in "200 OK" HTTP status) after the first successful rewrite. For example:

  ```
  # Only apply this rule to direct requests, not rewritten requests
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  :
  ```

---

#### Other notes:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L,END]
> ```

You don't need to specify both `L` and `END`. `END` does the same as `L` and more. In a `.htaccess` context `L` stops the current pass through the rewrite engine but then starts over. Whereas `END` (new with Apache 2.4) stops the current pass through the rewrite engine and stops any further processing by the rewrite engine.

However, the use of both `L` and `END` are unnecessary here. When specifying an `R` code outside of the 3xx range then processing stops anyway.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/multi [NC]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^multipart/form-data; [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ - [R=400,L,END]
> ```

You don't need the condition that checks against the `REQUEST_URI` server variable (in the first rule) as this check can be performed, more efficiently, in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* itself. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Content-Type} !^multipart/form-data [NC]
RewriteRule ^multi - [NC,R=400]
```

(Assuming the `.htaccess` file is in the document root, which comments appear to confirm it is.)

NB: This only applies to the first rule, not the second, which uses a *negated* expression.

> ```
> # Define Image Uploads directory, to be able to access img uploads while uploads are kept outside from document root
> RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /uploads/imgs/$1 [L]
> ```

It looks like this rule (near the end of the `.htaccess` file) is in the wrong place? I'm assuming requests of the form `/images/<image>` don't map directly to physical files so this rule should go *before* the front-controller pattern, otherwise it's never going to be processed.

(Nothing is "outside the document root" here, despite what the comment says.)